# What are some good online coding log/management tool?

Tags: project-management

I am looking for an online, free coding management tool, where I could log my coding process, for example, bugs to be fixed and has been fixed. What are some good recommendation?

Comment: Do you have a bug tracker up and running already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely check out [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/home), it has a lot of functionality and is constantly improving.

But what I like about it most, is that you can enable features on an as-needed basis, and customize each project ( workspace, as they are called on Assembla ) with only the features it needs. I used it for around three months for a collaborative school project, and was very pleased. I would definitely use it again.

Also there is [github](https://github.com/), as of recently it has most of the features that made me choose Assembla for the school project ( such as milestones, and the ability to create issues/tickets ).

Assembla is a lot more flexible and with more capabilities, and can be adjusted to your team's development style ( with SCRUM-specific features, for example ). I find github suitable for projects on which I'm the only developer, but I wouldn't use it for team projects.

Answer (score 2):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) fits your fuzzy description pretty well. It integrates a lot of functionality.

At the same time, all you want to do could easily be done with a spreadsheet in Google Docs.